# wxpython: Why can't I check in wx.CheckListBox when Shift Key is down?

Tags: wxpython, keyevent, checklistbox

I intended to make a range of selections when shift key is down. However, when shift key is down, the wx.EVT_CHECKLISTBOX is not triggered. The following is my code:

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, "Different Frame", size=(300, 300))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.prevIndex = None
        self.shift_down = False
        self.level = wx.CheckListBox(panel, -1)
        levels = ["%s" % i for i in range(9)]
        self.level.SetItems(levels)
        self.level.Bind(wx.EVT_CHECKLISTBOX, self.OnSelectLevel)
        self.level.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.onKeyDown)
        self.level.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_UP, self.onKeyUp)

        panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

    def onKeyDown(self, event):
        print("onKeyDown")
        keycode = event.GetKeyCode()
        if keycode == wx.WXK_SHIFT:
            self.shift_down = True
        else:
            event.Skip()

    def onKeyUp(self, event):
        print("onKeyUp")
        keycode = event.GetKeyCode()
        if keycode == wx.WXK_SHIFT: 
            self.shift_down = False
        else:
            event.Skip()

    def OnSelectLevel(self, evt):
        print("OnSelectLevel")
        currindex = evt.GetInt()
        currCheckedItems = self.level.GetCheckedItems()
        if self.prevIndex != None and self.shift_down == True:
            if currindex > self.prevIndex:
                newrange = list(range(self.prevIndex, currindex))
            else:
                newrange = list(range(currindex, self.prevIndex, -1))
            newCheckedItems = currCheckedItems + newrange
            self.level.SetCheckedItems(newCheckedItems)
            self.prevIndex = currindex
            evt.Skip()

app = wx.App(0)
frame = MyFrame(None)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Is there anyway to trigger the event wx. EVT_CHECKLISTBOX while shift key is down? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your attribute `self.prevIndex` never gets set.
Try this modification:

```
def OnSelectLevel(self, evt):
    currindex = evt.GetInt()
    currCheckedItems = list( self.level.GetCheckedItems() )
    if self.prevIndex != None and self.shift_down == True:
        if currindex > self.prevIndex:
            newrange = list(range(self.prevIndex, currindex))
        else:
            newrange = list(range(currindex, self.prevIndex, -1))
        newCheckedItems = currCheckedItems + newrange
        self.level.SetCheckedItems(newCheckedItems)
    self.prevIndex = currindex
    evt.Skip()
```

Also, it's easier to just check in OnSelectLevel whether the Shift key is pressed or not using `wx.GetKeyState(wx.WXK_SHIFT)`.

In general, I always recommend to use a good debugger and set a breakpoint at the event handler. Then you can interactively inspect things and step through.

Comment: @ Dietmar Schwertberger: you are right that prevIndex never get set. But the problem here is when I press shift and try to check one item, that item won't get checked (the text "OnSelectLevel" can't be printed when shift is pressed).

Comment: Please state your platform. On Windows it's working fine. If it does not work on your platform, you may have to find a workaround (e.g. filter the events and post a modified event to the control.
Maybe, a sizer and checkboxes are the easier solution...

Comment: I got the same problem in the two platforms that I tested in. One is Darwin, python 3.6.5 Anaconda, 4.0.3 osx-cocoa (phoenix) wxWidgets 3.0.5. The other is Linux, Python 3.5.6, 4.0.3 gtk3 (phoenix) wxWidgets 3.0.5.

Comment: On Windows, wx uses a generic implementation of the checklistbox.
See here for the source: https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/master/src/msw/checklst.cpp
The implementation handles a EVT_LEFT_DOWN without checking for Shift.
On gtk a native CheckListBox seems to be available and being used.

Comment: If the native widget ignores Shift-Clicks, then you have only three ways:

 - try to filter the event and post a non-Shift-Click to the widget; I'm not 100% sure whether this will work

 - implement a CheckListBox like widget yourself; maybe use the Windows implementation as base, but do it in Python...

 - use a different widget like a grid that has more control over the events

If you don't find a solution yourself, I would suggest to ask on the wxPython mailing list.